# Changing background color of a div instead of the body

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to change the background in a div and not just the body with this code?

```js
function run(interval, frames) {
  var int = 1;

  function func() {
    document.body.id = "b" + int;
    int++;
    if (int === frames) {
      int = 1;
    }
  }

  var swap = window.setInterval(func, interval);
}

run(1000, 4000); //milliseconds, frames
```

Comment: Change `document.body` in the code to be a reference to the `div` element you want to target

Comment: You have to provide more code cause i can't see any body background color set in that function, you set an id which constantly changes, there must be other code that does the trick

Answer (score -2):

Dont know why r u using jquery for it,

you can simple do it with CSS:

```
body { background-color: red; }
.div { background-color: blue; }
```

Comment: The OP uses JS because they're changing the background colour every 4 seconds. This code does not do that